# Flutter/ googlemap with another layout on above

Tags: google-maps, flutter, flutter-layout

I'm trying to use google map in my flutter app by follow this plug-in
https://github.com/apptreesoftware/flutter_google_map_view

However, when I lunch the map screen

```
mapView.show(
  new MapOptions(
        mapViewType: MapViewType.normal,
        showUserLocation: true,
        initialCameraPosition: new CameraPosition(
            new Location(45.5235258, -122.6732493), 14.0),
        title: "Recently Visited"),
        toolbarActions: [new ToolbarAction("Close", 1)]);
```

It show the full screen map, and I cant do anything in layout.

Is there any way to add the custom layout (container, image ,etc...) on top of this map layout? (likes using stack())

Thanks you